# How to get current navigation state react-navigation V4 React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation's Stack Navigator from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/**4.x**/screen-tracking, but this works only in the case of onNavigationStateChange. Initially, when the application is launched, I want to fetch the Screen Name / Current Component Name

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  if (route.routes) {
    return getActiveRouteName(route);
  }
  return route.routeName;
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(AppRouteConfigs);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
       /********Getting the initial route name here**********/
  }
  render() {
    return (
  <AppContainer
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState, action) => {
          const currentRouteName = getActiveRouteName(currentState);
          const previousRouteName = getActiveRouteName(prevState);

          if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
            console.log('Current Component is - ' + currentRouteName);
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help in getting the current screen or component name in the initial launch for version 4.x

Comment: Hello, can you share the code of ```getCurrentRouteName``` method?